# Firebird SQL 3.0 login from legacy tools?

Tags: login, connection, firebird

New Windows 2016 server with Firebird 3 SuperServer x64 on port 3050.

I'm trying to connect to this server from two legacy tools: Sinática Monitor and FlameRobin. I can successfully connect with Upscene Database Workbench and Firebird Maestro, but the old tools fail, saying "Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to setup a Firebird login."

I have set firebird.conf as follows, and thought that would be sufficient:

```
AuthServer = Legacy_Auth, Srp, Win_Sspi
AuthClient = Legacy_Auth, Srp
```

For each connection attempt, firebird.log shows a message like this:

```
INET/inet_error: read errno = 10054, client host = HOSTNAME, address = 127.0.0.1/49652, user = LoggedInWindowsUser
```

What could be amiss?